# How do you use pandas read_csv() method if the csv is stored as a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to work with data in a google spreadsheet, reading it into a csv and then working with it as a dataframe using pandas.read_csv().

I can get the csv read out into a variable (the variable "data" below), but cannot then use pandas.read_csv() on the variable. I've tried casting it as a string, using os.cwd(), etc.

```
r = requests.get('I put my google sheets url here')
data = r.text
print(data)

#csv is printed out properly

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = data, header = 1, usecols = ["Latitude", "Longitude"])
print(df)
```

No matter what I try, I always get a FileNotFoundException.

I'm a python newbie, so I'm probably missing something something really obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the first parameter to `read_csv` is a string (as it is in your case) it treats it as a file path that it tries to open. Hence the FileNotFoundException.

You need your data in a file-like object. Try using io.StringIO like so:

```
import io

r = requests.get('I put my google sheets url here')
data = r.text
buffer = io.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = buffer, header = 1, usecols = ["Latitude", "Longitude"])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with StringIO:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="I put my google sheets csv url here"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```